# laravel 5.4, получить аутентифицированного пользователь в конструкторе контроллера

Tags: laravel

Как получить аутентифицированного пользователь в конструкторе контроллера?
В версии 5.2 с помощью фасада auth - работало. В 5.4 возвращает null.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

protected $user;

public function __construct {
 $this->user = Auth::user();
}
```

Так же, использовал способ из документации:

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->projects = Auth::user()->projects;

            return $next($request);
        });
    }
```

Тоже самое... Возвращается null в $user;

Comment: А покажите код с `$this->middleware`, который вы адаптировали для себя.

Comment: как ниже в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Такой вот код, как говорят [тут](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/authuser-in-controller-construct), должен работать:

```
protected $user;

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user= Auth::user();

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Comment: использовал, не работает

Comment: @TricK А вы точно авторизованы ? ? ?

Comment: точно, точно )))

Comment: если использовать Auth::user() не в конструкторе, а в методах. То все работает.

Comment: @TricK Ну правильно он в конструкторе не сработает, если просто так, а с middleware должен работать, как в примере, вот тебе даже кусок документации :) [session-in-constructors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors)

Comment: @Orange_shadow Я же написал, что делал так.

Comment: @TricK  `use Auth`  писал ? или пробовал `auth()->user()` ? выведи `dd(auth()->user())`

Comment: @Orange_shadow возвращает null